# rails3-generators does not add any generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
...
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl'
end

gem 'rails3-generators', :group => :development
...
```

I run bundle install/update. And then not all new generators (from rails3-generators) are added. haml generators are also missing:

```
artem:~/projects/merjis (master)$ rails g
...

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  mailer
  migration
  model
  observer
  performance_test
  plugin
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  session_migration
  stylesheets

ActiveRecord:
  active_record:devise

Authlogic:
  authlogic:session

Devise:
  devise
  devise:install
  devise:views

Jquery:
  jquery:install

Koala:
  koala:install

MongoMapper:
  mongo_mapper:install

Mongoid:
  mongoid:devise
  mongoid:install

Mustache:
  mustache:install

Rspec:
  rspec:install
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

As @shingara pointed, not all but only some generators are missing

Comment: Why do assume that ? Mongoid and MongoMapper generator are in this gem. and you can see it.

Comment: But factory girl, shoulda and haml are missing. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory girl, shoulda and haml do not have 'explicit' generators you can call using `rails generator`. You need to configure your application. Haml is automatic (through the `haml-rails` gem, so from now on, each time a model is generated, it will generate haml views.

For the factory-girl you have to edit `config\application.rb` and add

```
# Configure generators values
config.generators do |g|    
  g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture => true  
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir=>"spec/factories"
end
```

and shoulda you just need to require in your `spec_helper`.

Comment: You don't need to require shoulda in spec_helper. It is loaded from test environment gemset

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the rails3-generators plugin but in your config/application.rb file

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine :haml => this works for sure
  g.scaffold_generator :rails3-generators => if that is the generator to replace
end
```

you can find another example here: http://paulbarry.com/articles/2010/01/13/customizing-generators-in-rails-3